# Can I set the web.config file base URL?

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to get my PHP website running on an IIS server. I used the IIS URL Rewrite tool to convert my .htaccess file to get the rewrite portion. It almost seems to work, but I cannot set a base URL as I did in my .htaccess file. Therefore, when navigating to a page beyond my index page, it is loading the URL without adding a slash first. My site is nested in a sub folder.

For example, example.com/projects/project01 is my site, and clicking a link to go to another page would do this: example.com/projects/project01otherpage, instead of example.com/projects/project01/otherpage.

This is my web.config file, am what am I missing? It works great on a XAMPP server with .htaccess file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <remove value="index.php" />
        <add value="index.php" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is unavailable to set base URL in IIS. Please ensure you are hosting your porject in side a virtual application instead of a folder.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/. Of course, you can create a rule to filter the corrupted URL. {URL}= project01([^/]+)(/.*)?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this. It turned out I was missing a final / on my URL constant, and then everything worked fine.